# dask merge fails with keyerror

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I have a dask dataframe as below:

```
id  refseqno    xml
0   31110671    42  <my_xml> ...
1   34470834    6   <my_xml>...
2   35025043    19  <my_xml>...
3   37360536    7   <my_xml>...
4   44152211    10  <my_xml>...
5   45322759    15  <my_xml>..
```

I want to run group by on `id` so that same `id`'s are grouped together and values of `refseqno` are joined. Basically each `id` will have will have multiple `refseqno`. Output of grouping is then merged with original dataframe so as to get joined `refseqno`, `id` and `xml` values. But merge is failing with `KeyError: 'id'`

```
df_valid = df_output.groupby(['id']).refseqno.apply(lambda grp: ','.join(grp), meta=(('join', str)))
df_valid = df_valid.to_frame()
df_merge = dd.merge(df_output, df_valid, on=['id'], how='inner')
df_merge.compute()
```

Also, both `df_output` and `df_valid` are dask dataframes

```
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
```

Can I please know how to fix the same?

Answer (score 1):

After grouping, the `df_valid` dataframe has `id` as the index, not as a column, which is why merge does not work.
A couple of possible solutions for your issue:

- Set the index on the `df_output` dataframe and then perform a join:

`df_merge = df_output.set_index("id").join(df_valid, how="inner")`

- Reset the index on the `df_valid` dataframe so that `id` becomes a column for the merge:

`df_merge = dd.merge(df_output.reset_index(), df_valid, on=['id'], how='inner')`